# Unable to find exact meaning of Title of the paper which is in French

Tags: traduction, apprentissage

I am a masters student in Mathematics in an Asian Country. 
I am self studying a research paper which is originally in French. I am fluent in English and Hindi.

I used Google Translator for translation of French to English. The problem that occured is that now I am doubtful after reading 4 lemmas in Research Paper that the paper title was different and perhaps mistranslated by Google and that I am reading a different paper. Initially , I didn't realized this as I was reading lemmas and So the main results hadn't appeared. So, I am confused about the title of the paper.

Also, I am self studying and no one in my University is specialized in what I am studying. So, I can't ask anyone.

But as I use mathematics.stackexchange so I thought if there is a stackexchange site for FrenchFrench and found this side.

So, it's my humble request if anyone can translate me these lines accurately.

Lines are ->"Irrationalit´e d’une innit´edevaleurs de la fonction zêta aux entiers impairs. "

I shall be really thankful.

Comment: I read: irrationalité d'une unité de valeurs de la fonction zêta aux entiers impairs.
Which word(s) don't you understand?

Comment: In light of your status as a New Contributor, I'll view your question as asking if the French title as you quote it makes sense in French (& not as an arguably "off-topic" request for a translation of it into English). Granted, I'm neither French nor a mathematician, but it makes no sense to me. I think there's one major TYPO & should read: ["Irrationalité d'une **infinité** de valeurs de la fonction zêta aux entiers impairs."](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Irrationalit%C3%A9-d%E2%80%99une-infinit%C3%A9-de-valeurs-de-la-z%C3%AAta-Ball-Rivoal/8c8719c72a5fefeb25fcbb79aaa795f34446d8af)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I follow the hypothesis of "Papa Poule" about the term "innité" that you wrote and that doesn't exist in French. I think he is right to suppose the original word was "infinité". So the sentence would be:

*"Irrationalité d'une infinité de valeurs de la fonction zêta aux entiers impairs."*

and in English, that means:

*"Irrationality of an infinity of values of the zeta function at odd integers".*

Comment: That should actually be ***at** odd integers*; ***to** odd integers* doesn't make any sense in English.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have corrected the text.